# How to remove VS2010 "File modification detected" dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every time i switch branch in git, visual studio pisses me off with [those popups](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/283618/add-ignore-all-and-reload-all-buttons-to-file-modification-detected-dialog) asking me if I want to reload project or ignore changes.

How to automatically reload solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree. I cannot believe they did not fix it in VS 2010.

But just an FYI:

This one is closed [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616639/visual-studio-file-modification-detected-dialog-needs-reload-all-button-for-project-files?wa=wsignin1.0).

This one seems to be still active and has a workaround(which is not worth the time for me) : [Microsoft Active](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/482816/easier-way-to-reload-many-modified-projects-such-as-reload-all-or-automatic-reload?wa=wsignin1.0)

**I guess this tells you how seriously Microsoft takes this:** 
Issue is still outstanding from 5 years ago: 283618

Answer (score 6):

Try [VSCommands 2010 Lite](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf), it allows you to reload all projects:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this also very irritating, so i looked for a solution myself. And came up with a little console app I wrote, with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;


internal class Program
{
  // For Windows Mobile, replace user32.dll with coredll.dll
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

  // Find window by Caption only. Note you must pass IntPtr.Zero as the first parameter.
  [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
  static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  //      static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, ShowWindowCommands nCmdShow);
  static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

  internal static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     do
     {
        Console.Title = "Waiting...";
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "File Modification Detected");
        while ((int)hwnd == 0)
        {
           Thread.Sleep(500);
           hwnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "File Modification Detected");
        }

        Console.Title = "Found one, kill it...";
        Console.WriteLine("Found one, kill it...");
        // ShowNormal = 1
        // Show = 5
        ShowWindow(hwnd, 5);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
     } while (true);

  }
}
```

If you start this program, it waits for those popups, and clicks on Reload automatically.